# Access textField.text variables from different view controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm creating a login page with multiple `view controllers` and at the end of all the `view controllers` there will be a create account button. I want to be able to access all of the `textField.text` variables from every view controller. I tried to use core data and structs. However, xCode wouldn't compile it and would spit errors. Here is a ScreenShot of all the view controllers I need to pull data from: http://prntscr.com/lqt9b4

Answer (score 3):

"I want to be able to access all of the textField.text"

Do not do that. You should treat a view controller's views as private. You should create a model object (a class) and have each view controller change the relevant field(s) of the model object.

Alternately you can use a struct and pass a new copy each time it changes (since structs are value types.)

Comment: I'm new to swift. What would I do with the model and what would code would I put in it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reconsider how to do this. A sequence of VCs like this would require passing each part of the puzzle onto the next. If you want four VCs to work together, it maybe better to use a UIPageViewController-style arrangement, with the overall view controller then pulling data from each sub-VC.